# UIRefreshControl on UICollectionView with height very low

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have use UIRefreshControl on UICollectionView. I use it for load more data for UICollectionView. But, refresh is not run by height of UICollectionView is low.

Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by **refresh is not run by height of UICollectionView is low**?

Comment: Please add more detail your problems.

Comment: When i pull up UICollectionView, UIRefreshControl is show but can not complete and call my @selector. Because, height of UICollectionView is very short.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This instance, you don't need use @selector. You can use delegate of UIScrollView. You override function **- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView**

This is my code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -65 && ![refreshControl isRefreshing]) {
        [refreshControl beginRefreshing];
        //do all the work

        [refreshControl endRefreshing];
    }
}
```